# mysql, reformat data inside select sentence

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, reformat

my question may duplicated, I researched but I couldn't find out the answer I need.

My question is how can I re-formatting data from mysql select query.

`comlum_01` is Char and data like `07/25/2013` or `7/25/2013`.

I want to change query data to '`20130725`'.

Below is the sql sentence I want to make, change and put data in comlum `new_comlum`

```
Select A.comlum_01, reformat(A.comlum_01) as new_comlum from table_01 A;
```

this one looks like similar but...

[reformatting a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118549/reformatting-a-date)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: [Check this out](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: are you looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921574/how-to-convert-datetime-to-a-number-in-mysql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.comlum_01,  DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(A.comlum_01, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y%m%d') AS New_comlum 
FROM table_01 A;
```